# How can I find out what's changing the group for /dev/ttyUSB*, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, udev, dev

I've got a couple of USB devices that suddenly stopped working a few hours ago after several years of working fine and at least a week since I last touched the machine they were on.  After a bit of debugging I saw the /dev/ttyUSB* group was root rather than tty or dialup, and something in udev is forcing it back to root after a chgrp:

```
> ll /dev/ttyU*
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root    188,  0 Jan 23 00:51 ttyUSB0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root    188,  1 Jan 23 00:51 ttyUSB1
> sudo chgrp tty /dev/ttyUSB*
> ll /dev/ttyU*
crw-rw-r-- 1 root tty 188, 0 Jan 23 00:51 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root tty 188, 1 Jan 23 00:53 /dev/ttyUSB1
> sudo udevadm trigger
> ll /dev/ttyU*
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 188, 0 Jan 23 00:54 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 188, 1 Jan 23 00:54 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

There's nothing I can see in /etc/udev/rules.d that could be causing this, and adding an explicit rule with `KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", GROUP="tty"` has no effect, a `udevadm trigger` or reboot changes the group back to root again making the USB devices inaccessible.  The brute-force alternative of `chmod 777` has the same problem, udevadm sets it back to 644 again.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this, or how to find out what's causing it and disable it?  Something really, really doesn't want anything accessing the USB devices but it's not obvious what it is.  I've currently brute-forced it with `GROUP:="tty"` but that doesn't deal with the underlying problem.